# Is the union of all $l^p$ spaces meagre in $l^\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

Is the union of all $l^p$ spaces meagre in $l^\infty$? i.e. is $ \bigcup_{p=1}^\infty l^p$ meagre?

I am revisiting this variety of math after a long break so help is appreciated. Please correct anything I get wrong too.

I know that a space is meagre if it can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets, and that a set is nowhere dense if it is closed and has no interior points.

My attempts/ideas:

(1) I seem to remember that $l^1 \subset l^2 \subset l^3 \subset l^4 \subset ...\subset l^\infty$, but maybe I'm wrong about this? I can't seem to find it anywhere or prove it either. Is this true? If this were the case then it would be enough to show that $\bigcup_{p=1}^\infty l^p=l^\infty$ is meagre. Then I'm stuck again... how do I show that $l^\infty$ is meagre?

(2) There is already a countable union (of $l^p$s) here (do I have to show that it is countable? This is obvious isn't it?), so that makes me think that it would be good if I could show that each $l^p$ is nowhere dense. How could I do this?

Any critiques/ideas?

Comment: It seems to me you would need to specify the space in which you want to show that the union is meagre. Also, the union is contained in $\ell^\infty$, equality does not hold! Your comment (1) about the inclusion is true. In order to see why, note that $|x_n|<1$ for all but finitely many $n's$. This allows you to go from the a priori uncountable union of $p\in[1,\infty)$ to the countable union of $p\in\mathbb N$. Also, you may find http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942706/is-c-0-meagre-in-l-infty interesting.

Comment: @user161825 Sorry, I mean to show the union is meagre in $l^\infty$. Edited

Comment: @user161825 That's my question too! Will that one help me here too? I don't see how to apply it. Also, why doesn't the equality hold? You say that the union is contained within $l^\infty$ but isn't $l^\infty$ also contained in the union?

Comment: Hint: The union of all the $\ell_p$ spaces is contained in the space $c_0$ of all sequences that converge to $0$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Why is that true? I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that if
$$x\in \bigcup_{p\in[1,\infty)}\ell^p,$$
then $x\in \ell^p$ for some $1\leq p <\infty$. thus $\sum |x_n|^p<\infty$. In particular $|x_n|\rightarrow 0$, so
$$\bigcup_{p\in[1,\infty)}\ell^p\subset c_0.$$

Comment: Why does $|x_n| \to 0$?

Comment: What happens if it doesn't? Can the series then converge?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Oh ok, I understand why. So the union is a subspace of $c_0$. Then I want to show that the union is closed in $c_0$ and has no interior points? Implying that it is meagre. Is that right?

Comment: Rather, you want to argue that any subset of a meagre set is meagre.

Comment: @user161825 Is that a known theorem? Or is it really obvious and I'm just not seeing why?

Comment: The second. It is a consequence of the corresponding property for nowhere dense sets.

Comment: @user161825 Ok thanks. Sorry but another question: If $x \in$ the union, then what happens if $x \in l^\infty$. Doesn't this imply that $|x_n|<\infty$ but not necessarily tending to 0?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $\bigcup _p \ell^p \subsetneq c_0\subsetneq \ell^\infty$.

Comment: @user161825 But why? Because if $|x_n|$ does not tend to $0$ (for the $p=\infty$ case) then why is $\bigcup_p l^p \subset c_0$ ?

Comment: The union is over $p\in [1,\infty)$, not $p\in [1,\infty]$. So $\ell^\infty$ is not 'in' the union. Otherwise the union would be simply $\ell^\infty$, which is a Banach space and therefore definitely not meagre in itself.

Comment: @user161825 So $\bigcup_{p=1}^5$ does include $p=5$ but $\bigcup_{p=1}^\infty$ does not include $p=\infty$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the notation is ambiguous. Usually, I would interpret it as $\bigcup _{p=1}^\infty A_p=A_1\cup A_2 \cup \dots$, which does not include $A_\infty$. This is similar to the typical notation for summation. It is also the typical notation in measure theory (see for instance the [wiki page for measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))), where the set $E_\infty$ is usually not defined, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @user161825 Ok, ambiguous notation is what killed my efforts before I posted this question then. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Complementing Jonas answer, the sequence with terms $ x_k = \dfrac{1}{\ln(k+1)}$ for all $k\geq 1$ is in $c_0$, but it's not in any of the $l^{p}$ sets. Suppose, by contradiction, that $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \in l^{p}$. The idea to prove it is using Hölder's inequality and get the inequality, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum^{k}_{i=1} \dfrac{1}{ (1+k) \ln(k+1)}\leq \left(\sum^{k}_{i=1} \dfrac{1}{ (1+k)^{q}}\right)^{1/q}\left( \sum^{k}_{i=1} \dfrac{1}{\ln(k+1)^p} \right)^{1/p}$$ with $\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}=1$, which would, erroneously, mean that the sequence of terms $ y_k = \dfrac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}$ belongs to $l^{1}.$

The argument to derive that $(y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not in $l^{1}$ is to realize that, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
\int^{k}_{1} \dfrac{1}{(\tau+1)\ln(\tau+1)} d\tau = \ln(\ln(k+1))- \ln(\ln(2)) \leq \sum^{k}_{i=1} \dfrac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)},
$$ using the integral test for convergence.